# How to prevent XSS vulnerability with Struts

Tags: java, struts, xss

We need to add anti-XSS support in our Struts application. Most specifically the architect requires that all user input must be "sanitized" before storing in DB. As I don't want to reinvent the square wheel, which Java library can I use for this ? And where to put it ? Ideally it should be configurable (which input fields to check, not all of them in request) and fast. My first thought is Struts Validator.

Thanks in advance
Lluis

Comment: I think this is more of a programming question. This type of sanitation should be done at the client and data layers of your application.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you look into OWASP's [ESAPI project](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI).  It has been under development for over a year, and is approaching its 2.0 release.

For escaping values stored in the database, check out the Encoder.encodeForSQL() method ([reference implementation](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultEncoder.java)).

For input validation, check out the Validator ([reference implementation](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultValidator.java)).

Note:  my understanding is that the functionality provided by older projects such as Stinger and CSRFGuard is being included in ESAPI.

Answer (score 2):

If you seach google for XSS Java Filter, you'll come up with many open source solutions, such as this [one](https://xssfilter.dev.java.net/).

You could also look at the [OWASP validation project](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Validation_Project).