# XSS security issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts, xss

When using Cross Site Scripting - XSS in a J2EE struts 2.0.9 application . When I put `<Script>` tag in the URL it is executing the JavaScript which is a security threat. Is there any solution to overcome this problem apart from moviing to higher version of Struts.

Comment: How to prevent XSS vulnerability with Struts : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825638/how-to-prevent-xss-vulnerability-with-struts

Answer (score 0):

Make constant string array, and check this array for the right variable name when u request/call URL.

Example :

```
      http://localhost:8080/updaterecord.do?**name**="david"

      http://localhost:8080/updaterecord.do?**ssn**="10-787-78787-77"
```

The **name** and **ssn** push to string array, and validate URL parameter against this array.

Answer (score 0):

Just escape user-controlled input in the front end.

In JSP/JSTL you should use [`c:out`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html)

```
<c:out value="${input}" />
```

for user-controlled input instead of plain EL

```
${input}
```

The Struts equivalent of `c:out` is [`html:text`](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#text)

```
<html:text value="${input}" />
```

In Java source code you don't need to worry about this. It doesn't interpret JS in `String`s (unless you're using *Rhino* or so for that of course ;) ).